# Incorrect output for Java in a Morse to English program

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here is my Morse Code to English and Vice Versa assignment criteria:

1. In Morse Code, | stands for a blank space.
2. In Morse Code, a blank space stands for a new letter or digit.

My code is compiling correctly, but the output (after running it) is incorrect.

```
// Import Scanner.
import java.util.Scanner

public class Project1_szhu1249322
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to translate 'Morse Code' to English, or 'English' to Morse code? (Enter 'Morse Code' or 'English'.)");
    String unit1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a string of " + unit1 + " characters (for English, numbers and letters, only): ");
    String amountUnit1 = input.nextLine();
    if (unit1 == "Morse Code")
        toEnglish(amountUnit1);
    else if (unit1 == "English")
        toMorseCode(amountUnit1);
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid data. Enter 'Morse Code' or 'English' without the single quotes.");
}

public static void toMorseCode(String english)
{
    // Declare variables, arrays, and strings.
    int i = 0;
    int l = english.length();
    int i2 = 2 * i;
    String[] lowerAlphabet = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] upperAlphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] morseCode = {".-", "-...", "-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----"};
    morseCode[i] = lowerAlphabet[i];
    StringBuilder morseBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // for loops and if statements for result.
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        i2 = 2 * i;
        if (english.charAt(i) != ' ')
            morseBuilder.append(morseCode[i2]);
        else
            morseBuilder.append('|');

        if (morseBuilder.charAt(i - 1) != ' ' && morseBuilder.charAt(i + 1) != 0)
            morseBuilder.append(' ');
    }

    morseCode[i] = upperAlphabet[i];
    // for loops and if statements for result.
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        i2 = 2 * i;
        if (english.charAt(i) != ' ')
            morseBuilder.append(morseCode[i2]);
        else
            morseBuilder.append('|');

        if (morseBuilder.charAt(i - 1) != ' ' && morseBuilder.charAt(i + 1) != 0)
            morseBuilder.append(' ');
    }

    // Display results.
    System.out.println("The corresponding Morse code is " + morseBuilder + ".");
}

public static void toEnglish(String morse)
{
    // Declare variables, arrays, and strings.
    int i = 0;
    int l = morse.length();
    int i2 = i / 2;
    String[] lowerAlphabet = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] upperAlphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    String[] morseCode = {".-", "-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----"};

    morseCode[i] = upperAlphabet[i];
    String english;

    StringBuilder englishBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // for loops and if statements for result.
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        i2 = i / 2;
        if (morse.charAt(i) == '|')
        {
            englishBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        else
            englishBuilder.append(morseCode[i2]);
    }

    morseCode[i] = lowerAlphabet[i];
    // for loops and if statements for result.
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        i2 = i / 2;
        if (morse.charAt(i) == '|')
        {
            englishBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        else
            englishBuilder.append(morseCode[i2]);
    }

    // Display results.
    System.out.println("The corresponding English is " + englishBuilder + ".");
}
}
```

My output is like this:

```
Would you like to translate 'Morse Code' to English, or 'English' to Morse code? (Enter 'Morse Code' or 'English'.)
English
Enter a string of English characters (for English, numbers and letters, only): 
to be
Invalid data. Enter 'Morse Code' or 'English' without the single quotes.
```

It is not going to the right if-else branch. Instead of going to the unit1 == "English", it goes to the last else for Invalid Data.

Also, for the for loop in the toEnglish method, how should I set i2? I need i / 2, but only if the first character is not a blank space.

Comment: Could someone explain WHY it did give me the unexpected type error? I am facing it again and I don't know what to do again.

Comment: Is the code in the question exactly the code in your program? Here are the errors I can see at a glance: `morse.charAt(i) = '|'` should use `==` for comparision. The value of `i2` is never updated so will always be `0`. `morseCode[i] = upperAlphabet[i]; morseCode[i] = lowerAlphabet[i];` will result in `morseCode[i] = lowerAlphabet[i];` and you will never see it being `upperAlphabet[i]`. Not sure what the point of the second `if` statement is in `toMorseCode`

Comment: You shouldn't use Stack Overflow to debug your entire program for you. Stack Overflow is for posting one question and getting one answer. [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Learn how to use the debugger and step through your code. If you are still stuck, post another question

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: The second if is to give a space in between the characters.

Comment: I see the errors now, except for the i2 one, i2 = i / 2 or i * 2, so as i increases, so does i2.

Comment: `i2` is only calculated and assigned once. `i = 0; i2 = i * 2;` i2 is 0 here. `i = 1;`, i is now 1, but i2 isn't recalculated, it is still 0. You need to call `i2 = i * 2` again. You would be better off dropping `i2` and just calling `i*2` when needed in this case

Comment: Thanks (sorry about all that, you're a great help)!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating your *translated* string you should use the following instead of `charAt() =` which doesn't allow assignment:

```
StringBuilder bob = new StringBuilder();

for (...){
    if (...){
        bob.append(character);
    }
}
String english = bob.toString();
```

Also `i2` will always equal `0`.

There are a number of other small bugs in here. Carry on debugging and you will eventually solve them all.

Comment: Could you please look into my edited post and explain the next error and confusion? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

`morse.charAt(i)` is a function and cannot stand on the left side of assignment. If you need to replace the character, convert the string into char array first:

```
 char[] english = morse.toCharArray();
 english[i] = '|';
```

then you can convert back into string when done if needed (`new String(myArray)`). Read about [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

This is why the error is. As you are building the answer char by char, the most reasonable way to do is via `StringBuilder`, as @Milk suggests. Unlike an array, [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) knows how to grow and you do not need to specify the size when creating it.

Answer (score 0):

There's another error

> > Project1_szhu1249322.java:67: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
> >                     morseCode[i2] = english.charAt(i);

`morseCode[i2]` returns `String`, whereas `english.charAt(i)` returns primitive type `char`. Change to `morseCode[i2] = String.valueOf(english.charAt(i));` to bring them both to String

Comment: `charAt()` returns a primtive `char`. You need to wrap it in `String.valueOf()`.

Comment: I guess that works, but since I am more familiar with StringBuilder, I used Milk's answer, though I still will use yours sometime :).